# How do you implement Localization in Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF)?

Tags: wpf, localization

Please share you experiences regarding how you localized your WPF applications to support multiple languages and any resources that helped you in it?

Thanks for your feedbacks.

Comment: Not quite clear. Are you looking for a technical how-to answer or subjective stories? (Edit your question to clarify what it is you want.)

Answer (score 3):

For our WPF application, all of our strings are localized as resources in a `ResourceDictionary` that we put in a .xaml file named after the language (like en-US.xaml, ja-JP.xaml, etc).

For example, somewhere in the application a button might look like this:

```
<Button Content="{StaticResource Strings.FooDialog.BarButtonText}"/>
```

Each `ResourceDictionary` for the different languages would contain a version of it:

```
<sys:String x:Key="Strings.FooDialog.BarButtonText">Bar!</sys:String>
```

The `ResourceDictionary` is dynamically connected to the `Application.Resources` at runtime like this:

```
private static void LoadLocalizedStrings(CultureInfo uiCulture)
{
   ResourceDictionary stringsResourceDictionary = new ResourceDictionary();
   stringsResourceDictionary.Source = new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/Resources/Strings/" + uiCulture.Name + ".xaml");
   Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(stringsResourceDictionary);
}
```

Comment: Robert, I find your solution the most simple and easy to implement. The problem is that although the code runs OK, the visual studio environment complains about not finding the resource. Understandably, of course, since the resource dictionary hasn't been loaded yet. How do you cope with this?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if it is vague (above question),basically it about how you implemented it in your application and what you felt was the best way.It is basically to understand scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

I just localized my WPF application successfully using ResourceDictionary. The method I used allows for dynamic changing of languages, easy translation, design-time support, and even allows for partial translations. I based my work on http://www.geektieguy.com/2006/12/12/localizing-an-xbap-application-without-using-locbaml/

You can see my efforts in part at: [ResourceDictionary Source Binding to Module (for Localization)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623008/resourcedictionary-source-binding-to-module-for-localization)